# Do a Raycast after Raycast-positioned object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, raycasting, mesh-collider

I have a code that allows to position an object onto the other object by Raycast. Obviously, I am using Mesh Collider so everything works fine.

```
Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SelectableTrunk>())
        {
            RandomSTrunk.position = hit.point; 
        }
    }
```

My question is the next. Is it possible to place the object (as I did) and then do one more raycasting to place the other object onto the already placed one?

When I am trying to do that - The mesh collider on the first object is breaking everything and nothing works.

Comment: static bool RayCast ( Vector3 orgin , Vector3 direction , out RayCastHit hitInfo , float distnace=Mathf.Infinity , int layerMask=DefaultRaycastLayers );
The first parameter is the origin of the ray collision detection;
The second parameter is the direction vector of ray detection;
The third parameter is out type, which is used to get the return value of collision detection;
The fourth parameter is the ray length of collision detection;
The fifth parameter is collision detection only on the specified layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a layer for the hit object and then follow the code below:

```
public LayerMask hitPlaceLayer;

void RayCast()
{
    // first ray cast
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out var hit, hitPlaceLayer.value))
    {
        RandomSTrunk.position = hit.point; 
    }
    
    // second raycast
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, hitPlaceLayer.value))
    {
        otherRandomTrunk.position = hit.point; 
    }
}
```

define layer for Hit place object:

[image]

Layer mask for raycasts:
[image]